# Creating a csv file and reading it

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, csv

So in the first viewcontroller of my app trying to create a csv file containing a string but it doesn't work for some reason.Im using this code:

```
-(IBAction)initialButton:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"initialButton clicked");


    if([securityCode.text length] == 8){

        NSString *securtityCodeData = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",
                                       self.securityCode.text];
        NSString *docPath =[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentationDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES)objectAtIndex:0];
        NSString *securityCodes=[docPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"securityCodes.txt"];

        if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:securityCodes]){
            [[NSFileManager defaultManager]createFileAtPath:securityCodes contents:nil attributes:nil];
        }

        NSFileHandle *fileHandel = [NSFileHandle fileHandleForUpdatingAtPath:securityCodes];
        [fileHandel seekToEndOfFile];
        [fileHandel writeData:[securtityCodeData dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [fileHandel closeFile];

        NSLog(@"security code has been saved\nSecurity code:%@",securtityCodeData);


        NewTrackTraceViewController *newTrackTraceViewController = [[NewTrackTraceViewController alloc]init];

        AppDelegate *appDelegate = [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
        [appDelegate.transitionController transitionToViewController:newTrackTraceViewController withOptions:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve];

        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:@"HasLaunchedOnce"];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];





} else {
    [WCAlertView showAlertWithTitle:@"Security code is not valid"
                            message:@"Please enter a valid securitycode to continue."
                 customizationBlock:^(WCAlertView *alertView) {

                     alertView.style = WCAlertViewStyleVioletHatched;

                 } completionBlock:^(NSUInteger buttonIndex, WCAlertView *alertView) {

                 } cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"Okay",nil];
}

}
```

Then we push to my second viewcontroller an there i want to read the csv file and put its content in a label:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSString *docPath =[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentationDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES)objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *securityCodes=[docPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"securityCodes.csv"];

    if([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:securityCodes]){

        securityCodeLabel.text = securityCodes;
        NSFileHandle *fileHandel = [NSFileHandle fileHandleForReadingAtPath:securityCodes];
        NSString *securityCodeData=[[NSString alloc]initWithData:[fileHandel availableData] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        [fileHandel closeFile];

        self.securityCodeLabel.text=securityCodeData;
        NSLog(@"%@",securityCodeData);
    }else{
        NSLog(@"File does not exist");
        self.securityCodeLabel.text=@"No security code found!";

    }
}
```

What Im doing wrong? For some reason the file is not saved..

Comment: Do you mean to be writing to the NSDocumentationDirectory instead of NSDocumentDirectory?

Comment: Awesome that was the problem thanks alot :D

Comment: Side note: change this: `NSString *securtityCodeData = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", self.securityCode.text];` to this: `NSString *securtityCodeData = self.securityCode.text;`. Do not use string formats unless you actually have a string to format.

Comment: Side note 2: No need for file handles to read a file into an `NSString`. Simply use `NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:encoding:error:`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NSDocumentationDirectory should be NSDocumentDirectory.